# VSCode, Python: error: release unlocked lock

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, ptvs

I am running a python process in a remote Linux machine and debug with a MAC.

The remote system launches processes that share the same set of files.

From time to time when stepping through code, I hit the following:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ptvsd/visualstudio_py_debugger.py", line 1623, in loop
cmd()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ptvsd/visualstudio_py_debugger.py", line 1895, in command_execute_code
thread.run_on_thread(text, cur_frame, eid, frame_kind, repr_kind)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ptvsd/visualstudio_py_debugger.py", line 1223, in run_on_thread
self.schedule_work(lambda : self.run_locally(text, cur_frame, execution_id, frame_kind, repr_kind))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ptvsd/visualstudio_py_debugger.py", line 1215, in schedule_work
self.unblock()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ptvsd/visualstudio_py_debugger.py", line 1211, in unblock
self._block_lock.release()
error: release unlocked lock
```

Is there a recipe to debug identical remote python processes using PTVS/VSCode?

I follow the documented steps by adding the call to invoke the `ptvsd` server in remote process on specific port and attach to it in my local debugger.

Can the debugger handle a parallel instance of the same process ?